# How to find a list of nodes matching a relationship pattern in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have to find all nodes, `x1` `x2` `x3` such that `x1-[:R1]->x2-[:R2]->x3`.

Here `R1` and `R2` will be known aforehand, and we have to find all such `x1` `x2` `x3` which match the condition. Also, the number of relationships may increase or decrease i.e there could be three relationship `R1` `R2` `R3` and it should return all `x1` `x2` `x3` `x4` which satisfies the condition.

I need to do this using Java API and not Cypher queries.

I found the classes PatternNode and PatternRelationship, but found it hard to understand and how to construct them in order to achieve what I want to achieve. Also both the classes are deprecated. Is there a way I could achieve this through Java?

Comment: Why do you want to do this via Java if Cypher can handle it? You can use Cypher from Java using ExecutionEngine.

Comment: I Agree, why not Cypher? this is a trivial query in Cypher, and you get the benefit of performance increases each time Cypher gets optimised. Usually I only use the traversal API when I can't get the required performance. This query is so simple that I wouldn't have thought performance would be an issue.

Comment: That was a requirement from my project manager, most probably because he needs to implement his own query language for a very particular set of data. And he doesn't want to build that query language over Cypher and wants to achieve that over Java API function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of ways to traverse a graph in java. These are your options:

**Execute a Cypher query**

Use the ExecutionEngine to execute a Cypher Query:

```
final ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDB);
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute("YOUR_CYPHER_QUERY");
```

**Use the Cypher DSL syntax**

Again, you're basically writing a Cypher query, but this time, your using a nice DSL statement. Check out https://github.com/neo4j/cypher-dsl.

```
Execute q = start(node("john", john)).
            match(path().from("john").out("friend").link().out("friend").to("fof")).
            returns(properties("john.name", "fof.name"));
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( q.toString() ).toString();
```

**Use the traversal API**

You control the complete graph traversal. An example:

```
for (final Path position : Traversal.description().depthFirst()
    .relationships(RelationType.RELATIONSHIP_TYPE, Direction.INCOMING).traverse(node)) {
   System.out.println(position.endNode();
}
```

It's up to you, but I'd prefer a simple Cypher statement.